# Writing a static value returning method

Tags: java, methods, static

My assignment is: Write a static value returning method called max that has two int parameters, num1 and num2, and returns the larger of the two integers.

so far I've written the main part out just need help with the right method

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MaxLab {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String inputLine;
        int number1;
        int number2;
        Scanner in;
        in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter first number:");
        number1 = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter second number:");
        number2 = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("The largest number is " + max(number1, number2));
    }
 }
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

Comment: which bit don't you understand? How to compare the numbers? How to write a method that returns a value? How to write a static method?

Comment: Did you tried to write the Condition to find **LARGE NUMBER** ?

Comment: What outside resources did you look at before asking this, and which part of either writing a method or writing code to find the larger number did you find confusing?

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int max(int num1, int num2) {
  return Math.max(num1, num2);
}
```

Maybe the above would be considered a shortcut for the purpose of the exercise. In that case, here's the expanded form:

```
public static int max(int num1, int num2) {
  return num1 > num2 ? num1 : num2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic static method:

```
public static int max(int num1, int num2) {
    if(num1 > num2) return num1;
    else return num2;
}
```

That should work.

Comment: So if `num1 == num2` you return 0?

Comment: Return `num1` or `num2`. It's not logic that `max(4,4) = 0`. It's 4.

Comment: You could do it simpler: `if(num1 > num2) return num1; else return num2;`

Comment: I guess yeah. Good Idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class stackoverflow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(max(10, 20));//replace the arguments with users input
    }
    public static int max(int num1, int num2){
        int biggest = Math.max(num1, num2);
        return biggest;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So far I've seen

```
if(num1 > num2) return num1;
if(num1 < num2) return num2;
return num1;
```

and

```
return num1 > num2 ? num1 : num2;
```

I wouldn't go with the first one, a shorter way to write it using `else` is:

```
if(num1 > num2) {
    return num1;
} else {
    return num2;
}
```

The second way is called a ternary operator. It is of the syntax

```
[boolean expression] ? [returns this if true] : [returns this if false];
```

As you can see it is essentially equal to what I have written out above, and in fact it compiles to the same thing. If you've never seen it, however, it might be confusing.

Answer (score -3):

```
System.out.println("The largest number is " + Math.max(number1,number2));
```

Comment: The OP has to write a static method, not just use one

Comment: As this is an assignment, I guess he is supposed to write the method himself.

Comment: Way to ruin the joke, Captains Obvious. The *exact answer* is [here](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Math.java.html#801).